# how to "add" things together python

Tags: python

I wrote a function like this, the `op` gives a operation sign which like `'+','-','*','/'` or more, the code "adds" everything use the given operator,

**Here is the code:**

```
def arithmetic(op,*args):
  result = args[0]
    for x in args[1:]:
       if op =='+':
           result += x
       elif op == '-':
           result -= x
       elif op == '*':
           result *= x
       elif op == '/':
           result /= x
  return result
```

Is there a way i can use the `+,-,*,/` directly? So I don't have to write an If-Else statement?

Comment: Often, the easiest way to avoid an `if/elif` clause is to use a dictionary.  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for the builtin `reduce` function combined with `operator`:

```
import operator
a = range(10)
reduce(operator.add,a) #45
reduce(operator.sub,a) #-45
reduce(operator.mul,a) #0 -- first element is 0.
reduce(operator.div,a) #0 -- first element is 0.
```

Of course, if you want to do this using strings, you can map the strings to an operation using a dict:

```
operations = {'+':operator.add,'-':operator.sub,} # ...
```

then it becomes:

```
reduce(operations[your_operator],a)
```

Comment: … and using something like `{'+': operator.add, …}`

Answer (score 10):

You can use the corresponding [operators](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html):

```
import operator
def arithmetic(opname, *args):
    op = {'+': operator.add,
          '-': operator.sub,
          '*': operator.mul,
          '/': operator.div}[opname]
    result = args[0]
    for x in args[1:]:
       result = op(result, x)
    return result
```

or shorter, with [`reduce`](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

```
import operator,functools
def arithmetic(opname, arg0, *args):
    op = {'+': operator.add,
          '-': operator.sub,
          '*': operator.mul,
          '/': operator.div}[opname]
    return functools.reduce(op, args, arg0)
```

Answer (score 1):

For the `+` operator, you have the built-in `sum` function.

Answer (score -1):

You can use exec:

```
def arithmetic(op, *args):
 result = args[0]
 for x in args[1:]:
   exec('result ' + op + '= x')
 return result
```